# Обработка ошибок c++

Tags: java, c++, исключения

Только начал изучать обработку ошибок на с++, но до этого был знаком с java. Вот там работает такая конструкция:

```
try {
    int d = 2/0;
}
catch(ArithmeticException t) {
    System.out.println("Error!!!");
}
```

И сразу же захотелось реализовать что-нибудь подобное на с++, но к моему сожаление я не обнаружил никаких готовых классов, кроме `exception`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может я где не доглядел, есть ли какие-нибудь готовые конструкции/классы? Как реализовать подобную конструкцию на плюсах? Можно ли вообще создавать исключения без ключевого слова `throw`?

---

Если есть ссылки с большим/хорошим материалом по обработке ошибок на c++, подкиньте, пожалуйста.
Правильно ли я понимаю,что на c++ вообще нет ничего готового, как в java, и всё приходится делать ручками?

Comment: В с++ любой объект можно выбросить как исключение. Например `throw new int(10)`.  Вообще исключения не сильно свойственны с++,  чтобы поймать NPE нужно писать не тривиальный платформенного зависый код... Из частых исключение - bad_aloc когда память не выделили, других я даже и не вспомню сразу... Но метод с - сначала проверить а потом делать, не наоборот

Comment: Иерархия классов исключений в С++11 здесь: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/

Comment: Вообще помимо стандарта есть ряд хороших практик и в языке есть своя идеология. По поводу исключений можете посмотреть тут: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions

Answer (score 4):

Конкретно по конструкции в Вашем вопросе: в C++ это исключение поймать нельзя, для этого придётся использовать платформо-зависимое API, т.к. деление на 0 это исключение(trap) процессора.

Если же говорить в общем, то в C++ есть вот [такие](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) базовые классы, которые можно либо использовать непосредственно, либо наследоваться от них и уже производить свои классы-исключения, т.е. в этом плане, отличия от Java минимальны. Но наследоваться вовсе не обязательно — любой тип может быть использован в качестве исключения, т.е. нет никаких специальных типов-исключений, есть просто типы, которые можно использовать для создания и перехвата исключений.

Также можно добавить, что желательно все классы-исключения в приложении наследовать от одного класса, чтобы можно было разом поймать все исключения в одном месте(например в `main`). Т.к. все стандартные классы-исключения наследуют `std::exception`, наследование своих от оного может быть хорошей идеей.

Comment: Добавил бы, что собственные классы-исключения даже не обязательно наследовать от `std::exception`, хотя желательно.

Comment: @andy.37, а почему желательно? Там кроме метода what ничего нет?

Comment: @chebakov-grisha в общем, ни зачем, кроме некоего единообразия кода, имхо. Хотелось бы использовать все исключения похожим образом.

Comment: @chebakov-grisha Так вам никто не мешает строить свою иерархию. Но зато вы сможете перехватить в крайнем случае все, что бы ни произошло, в `main()` и по крайней мере получить хоть что-то похожее на вразумительную информацию о том, что случилось... P.S. Крайне рекомендую взять Саттера - те же "Решение сложных задач на С++" и "Новые сложные задачи" и почитать разделы, посвященные исключениям.

Answer (score 1):

Начну издалека. Давайте посмотрим на стандартную библиотеку языка. Сразу бросается в глаза, что исключения там почти не используются, особенно если сравнивать с Java, где на каждый чих принято бросать исключения. Например, посмотрим на описание алгоритма `std::copy`:

> The ranges shall not overlap in such a way that result points to an
>   element in the range [first,last).

Что будет если мы не выполним это условие?

> Note that invalid arguments cause undefined behavior.

А чёрт его знает. Может исключение, может бесконечный цикл, а может форматирование жесткого диска. Короче, undefined behavior.
В стандартной библиотеке не принято запрещать программисту выстрелить себе в ногу, если он этого хочет.
Что касается вашего примера, он при таком подходе выглядел бы так:

```
double div(double x, double y){
    return x/y;
}
```

А корректность входных данных пусть остается на совести того, кто эту функцию вызвал.

Теперь непосредственно к вашему вопросу. Стандартного исключения при делении на ноль нет. [Вот все что есть](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/?kw=exception). Если очень хочется выполнять деление с исключениями то можно написать так

```
class DivisionByZeroException{};
double div(double x, double y){
    if(y == 0){
        throw DivisionByZeroException();
    }
    return x/y;
}
```

И потом использовать эту функцию. Однако настоятельно вам не рекомендую это делать. От исключений в С++ больше проблем чем пользы. Они медленные, исключения в конструкторах ведут к утечкам памяти, исключения в деструкторах ведут к неопределенному поведению, исключения в методах со спецификатором noexcept ведут к аварийному завершению программы, исключения во время обработки исключений также ведут к аварийному завершению программы.

Comment: Можете пояснить, когда исключение из конструктора ведёт к утечке памяти? И вы уверены, что разворачивание стека всегда медленное?

Comment: Вещественное деление не нуля на 0 вполне себе валидно.

Comment: @user1056837, [пример](http://ideone.com/kcYdNy)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Нет, конечно, можно взять и выстрелить себе в ногу, а после этого обвинять пистолет... Не должен язык защищать от каждого чиха - потому как если вы создадите систему, которой сможет пользоваться любой дурак - только дурак ею и будет пользоваться. P.S. И ваши доводы **против** применения исключений - честно говоря, так и напоминают "не умеете вы их готовить" :) Не сбивайте с толку не определившуюся еще молодежь!

Comment: Пример с утечками по большому счету никак не связан с конструктором, так можно в любой функции сделать. Надо просто придерживаться RAII и будет всё в порядке.

Comment: @alexolut, нет дело именно в конструкторе. Проблема в том, что не вызывается деструктор частично созданного объекта. На счет RAII вы правы, стоит заменить обычный указатель на умный и утечки не будет.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb в том и дело, т.к. деструктор не вызывается этот код равносилен просто вызову new с последующим throw, из-за которого код с delete не будет выполнен.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, умный указатель - не панацея, и в ряде случаев - еще один способ выстрелить себе в ногу, это наглядно демонстрирует статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/191018/

Comment: По поводу комментариев @Harry и alexolut - возможно Вы и правы в том, что язык не должен защищать от всего, что нужно придерживаться RAII, но!, C++ явно не тянет на эту роль, он не защищает вообще не от чего.
Просто посмотрите сколько мучений взваливают на себя программисты, далеко не глупые программисты, когда в программе нужно найти утечку памяти или ошибку в коде. А если писать программы
более менее безопасно (например использовать те же умные указатели, вектора и прочее) - это опять же снижение производительности, которая сводит на нет какой либо смысл использовать C++.

Comment: Язык должен быть комфортным и понятным, а так получается что вместо Audi (Java, C#) - вы катаетесь на древней копейке (причем не BMW, а древних Жигулях). Акститесь и не учите молодеж плохому. Нужно выбирать перспективный язык, а не ржавое корыто. p.s. среди знакомых программистов-нативщиков наблюдается нехорошая тенденция спиваться(, подумайте об этом...

Comment: @Align, Во-первых, рассуждения "С++ vs Java vs C#" немного выходят за рамки этого вопроса. Во-вторых, эти споры сами по себе большая глупость и звучат как "Кто сильнее слон или кит?". В-третьих, у любого языка есть своя область применения, и свои недостатки.

Comment: @Align Что касается меня, то я предпочитаю потрепанный "Запорожец" с хорошим движком внутри, который при всей своей невзрачности довезет меня и пару тонн в прицепе туда, куда надо, чем что-то сверкающее, внутри которого будет нечто непонятное :) Кстати, в первую очередь мне активно не нравятся в Ауди сборщики мусора - которые лишают меня части управления происходящим. Предпочитаю искать утечки памяти сам :) И еще - уже давно С++ предрекают закат, гибель etc - не говорю уж о C :) - но это делают спецы, которые в одну кучу "языков программирования" валят C++, Java, HTML и CSS :)